# Black Screen when loading View from SceneDelegate

Tags: swift, swift5

I get an nearly black screen when I try to load this view. But if I add **view.backgroundColor = .red** it shows the color red correctly. Just the settings I did in Storyboard wont get shown.

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


     func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
   
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    
    
    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    window?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultsViewController") as! ResultsViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    
}


import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UINavigationController {

   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
          
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
view.backgroundColor = .blue
        
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have created the `ResultsViewController` in the storyboard. You'll have to load it from the storyboard to set it as `rootViewController`.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
window?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultsViewController") as! ResultsViewController
```

Note: Don't forget to set the identifier for `ResultsViewController` as "ResultsViewController" in the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: I edited the code in the first post like above and also changed the Storyboard ID which was empty. But it still shows the same result. Did I paste your code in the right place?

Comment: Yes, it's the right place. Join me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219912/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-63438847-black-screen-when-loading-view-from).